# Getting Not Recurring Random Strings With Generex Library

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting random strings according to a regex via Generex Library. I have a simple code to test "Does Generex produces same strings or not?". When I run this code I'm getting the size of list between 5000-5300.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            Generex generex = new Generex("[a-zA-Z0-9-]*");
            String randomString = generex.random();
            if (!stringList.contains(randomString)) {
                stringList.add(randomString);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stringList.size());
    }
```

The size of list means that Generex produces same strings and all strings are not distinct.

How can I guarantee that Generex will produce distinct Strings for every running of code? Does Generex has an ability to do this?

Comment: Why not use `Set` instead to `List` to ensure you have only unique elements in your collection.

Comment: Of course, Set can be used in this situation but I think that there is no effect for this situation. Because Generex produces same Strings. I need to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated on Generex Github page the libarary has a number of features, the main one being:

> Generate Random String that match the Regex.

Please note they are claimed to be random but *not unique*.

I have checked on their source code. The library is using initial pseudo random number generated with `Random` class to get initial value. As `Random` doesn't guarantee uniqueness the same `Generex` doesn't.

The interesting feature of the library is that they are using previous key mutations to get the next one (with random difference) but in lexographical order.

> Prepare an iterator that loop over all the Strings that matches the Regex. even if the set of String that matches the given Regex is infinite.

So you can use

```
    Iterator iterator = generex.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
    }
```

To get the list of strings where each next string is greater (in lexographical order) than the previous. Thus they will be unique.

A bit more wide used way to get unique strings (if you don't care about the regex) is to use [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()) class

```
String uniqueRandom = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you get distinct generated string for each running code ? you can use Generex#getAllMatchedStrings to get all distinct strings that match your regex (avoid using this method if there is unlimited possible string that match the regex), or you can use Generex's Iterator to iterate over all generated, you can also specify the value of seed that will be used when you call Generex#random it helps reusing the same pseudo random order.